# Issues with Incorrect Cross References in Overleaf PDF Export

Tags: cross-referencing, overleaf

Hello LaTeX Community,

I am experiencing an issue with cross references in my Overleaf project. I have been following the [Overleaf tutorial to create cross references](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf) within my document. While most references work as expected, a few of them are behaving incorrectly upon exporting the document to PDF.

Specifically, some cross references that should point to certain figures or sections are instead redirecting to incorrect locations, such as unrelated tables or sections. This issue does not occur consistently but affects only a few references without any apparent pattern.

I have double-checked the labels and references for typos, and everything seems to be in order.

To clarify, my expectation for these cross-references in the PDF is that they should not link to any document part (because these references are related to out-of-document parts), reflecting the majority of my references. However, some are still linking to elements within the current paper without any clear reason.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: typically this happens either because the \label is in the wrong place (The command must be issued *after*  the command that sets the anchor (e.g. the \caption command) or because you used the same label name twice (the log-file would tell you that).

Comment: if you have incorrect latex source latex will make incorrect output, but if you show neither the source nor the output it is hard to help (but putting ``\label`  before `\caption` is a common error)

Comment: Cross-references link `\ref{}` to `\label{}` within a single document. They don't reference things not in that document. Is that what you're trying to do?